# How can i make my ads fit into body width

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, ads

I have installed ads on my website recently and everything works fine in desktop version. I want to change the ads basing on the screen weight, i have ads code like :

```
<script type="text/javascript>
<script src="file.js">
<iframe>AD CODE </iframe>
</script>
```

I want to dynamicly change ads from desktop to mobile code basing on screen width using javascript but the problem is when i try to insert code into the ad zone the script 'js' inside will not run and the ad doesnt show.

What is the best practice to do so ?

Thanks to all of you

Comment: To clarify, you want a script within "file.js" to identify the width of the users screen and if the width is under a certain size to run a script specific to mobiles?

Comment: Yes, i want to insert specifi ad for each screen size

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want the users screen width or width of the window. If you're trying to determine if the user is using a mobile phone then screen width would likely be most suitable.

```
var width = window.screen.availWidth;
if(width < 400){
   //do mobile relevant action
} else {
   //do desktop relevant action
};
```

This question has been answered very thoroughly here: 
[Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: Thanks you for aswering, but when i do this way the script file.js inside the code does not run(load) and the ad doesnt show

Comment: Can you show the contents of "file.js" within your original question? Also, I'd assume that you would want the iframe tag outside of your script tag.